# Javascript Function script on foreach class of the dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-content

so i have this javascript function

```
function validation(step){
    var lines = [];
    $.each($('#part1row').find('.countall').html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/), function(i, line){
      var lineremnbsp = line.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
      var lineremspace = lineremnbsp.replace(/ /gi,'');
      if(lineremspace != ''){
          lines.push(parseInt(lineremspace));
      }
    });
    var sum = lines.reduce(getSum, 0);
    console.log(sum);
    if (sum !== 100){
      var countall = false;
    }
    if (countall == false){
      $.toast({
          heading: 'Alert',
          text: 'Jumlah Field Weight harus 100%',
          position: 'top-right',
          loaderBg: '#FFC107',
          icon: 'warning',
          hideAfter: 3500
      });
      return false;
    }

    if (countall == true){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

and the validation function is for this a specific td, which is the td with `.countall` class ,

[this is the table , the red box is the td with countall class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRApJ.png)

and the problem is that , as you can see in the image , i got an "Add More" button , and when i add a new row, the validation function ignore the countall class inside the new row , anyone know how to fix this ? , thanks for your help

**EDIT 2
--------------------------**

this is the add more function

```
function addMore(){
  var step = '<?=$pmpdocument->completion?>';
  if (step == 'step1') {
    var content = '<tr>'+
          '<td class="editable" data-step="step1">Double Click to Edit...</td>'+
          '<td class="editable advance" data-step="step1">Double Click to Edit...</td>'+
          '<td class="editable numberonly countall" data-step="step1">Double Click to Edit...</td>'+
          '<td class="marked numberonly" data-step="step3"> </td>'+
          '<td class="marked numberonly" data-step="step4"> </td>'+
          '<td class="marked" data-step="step4"> </td>'+
          '<td data-step="step5" class="numberonly"> </td>'+
          '<td data-step="step5" class="numberonly"> </td>'+
          '<td data-step="step5"> </td>'+
          '<td data-step="step5"> </td>'+
        '</tr>';
      $("#part1row").append(content);
      var newnumber = parseInt($("#part1row").attr('data-row')) + 1;
      $("#part1row").attr('data-row', newnumber);
      var datarow = parseInt($("#part1row").attr('data-row'));
      if (datarow > 1) {
        $("#removerow").show();
      } else {
        $("#removerow").hide();
      }
  }
}
```

i've been lookin for it on google, and many people only talk about the click function on dynamic element , like for dynamic element you should use

```
$(document).on('click', '#idname', function(){});
```

Instead of

```
$(#idname).on('click', function(){});
```

and it works for dynamic element , and i used it for the project as well , but i still don't know how to like re-call the validation function to re-detect the new DOM element, if anyone know how to do it , that'll be very helpful , thanks again for your help

Comment: You should add the function to add a new row in your question, something must be wrong with the row generation if the validation only fails with the new rows

Comment: I believe his problem is validation is ignoring new row, not other way around

Comment: Consider using classes rather than IDs for iteration.  Also, consider adding an infinite page sniffer that scans the page for new rows and binds the event to the new row when it finds it.

Comment: i just edit it and add the "Add More" function to the post, you guys can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i try to change the code from

```
$.each($('.countall[data-step="1"]').html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/), function(i, line){
      var lineremnbsp = line.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
      var lineremspace = lineremnbsp.replace(/ /gi,'');
      if(lineremspace != ''){
          lines.push(parseInt(lineremspace));
      }
    });
```

to

```
$('.countall[data-step="step1"]').each(function(key, val){
      var liness = $(this).html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/);
      $.each(liness, function(i, line){
        var lineremnbsp = line.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
        var lineremspace = lineremnbsp.replace(/ /gi,'');
        if(lineremspace != ''){
            lines.push(parseInt(lineremspace));
        }
      })
    });
```

and eventually it works

Answer (score 0):

When you add to the DOM the validation event handler isn't applied to the new element. The event handler only affects elements on the DOM when the event handler is applied. Therefore, when you add a new row you need to re-call your validation event handler.